# What's as…as mean in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning, as, comparative-constructions

> Nor was he the first person to be remembered more as the name of his code than as himself.

I think this sentence's main idea is: he is not first person whose name of his code famous than himself. But why use as…as?

Comment: It's not "as ... as ...", it's "more as ... than as ...". They're totally different things.

Comment: I think he missed the what the sentence structure *really* is, as well.

Comment: I got it wrong, I thought it‘s  'as ……as ……' .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me parse: (parts separated with pipes)

> |Nor was he the first person *| to be remembered more | as the name of his code |  ***than*** | as himself |*.

The structure is essentially:

> to be remembered more **as** X ***than*** **as** Y

"as... as" isn't the structure. It is a comparative "X than Y" construction. The two "as" words link the *remembered* to X and Y.

That "than" is a comparative conjunction, to compare how well-remembered the name was in one aspect (as X), compared to another.